# What is a better way of waiting for key press C++

Tags: c++

**Sounds like a silly question I know how to do it in C# can you please help!**

---

**C++ Example:**

```
  char input;
  cin>>input;                       
  if (input == '1')
  {  
      //Put code here!
  }
```

**C# Example:**

```
   if (option.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)         
   {
     //Put code here!
   }
```

Comment: Assuming windows, take a look at microsofts library

Comment: Are you writing a console application or a GUI application?

Comment: `cin>>input;` requires you to commit the value using the [ENTER] key. Check the [`cin.get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) function.

Comment: It's a console application!

Comment: Hi @πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks would this way of doing it solve the problem with multiple keys or would the application still look for the first input! for example if you pressed key two would you have to press it twice?

Comment: @mattcoder You should add these conditions and constraints to your question (or at least explain the exact behavior of c# `option.Key`).